# What is the meaning of this.attribute when it should be this->attribute

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, watch

I'm working on a C++ program, and while debugging I was in following function:

```
int CClass::do_something()
{
  ... // I've put a breakpoint here
}
```

My `CClass` has an attribute, let's call it `att`.

When my program is halted at my breakpoint, I've put three things in my Watch window:

```
att
this->att
this.att
```

The first two, `att` and `this->att` contain the correct value, but `this.att` contains a wrong value (at least it looks wrong).

The fact that it shows value means that `this.att` has some kind of meaning.
What is that meaning? What is the meaning of `this.att` compared to `this->att`?

For your information, I'm using Visual Studio as a development environment.

Comment: What compiler and debugger are you using? Xcode uses clang lldb which actually "fixes" it for you.. IE: http://i.imgur.com/fXBfOSE.png It knows you screwed up.

Comment: `this` is a pointer so you should use `this->att`. The `.` is to invoke a method, which pointers do not have since they are primatives, therefore that syntax is illegal

Comment: Yes, and as a consequence of this, the code should not even compile and hence it is interesting that you are able to debug it. Well, does the expression `this.att` appear in your program at all? Maybe, it is just a debugger bug (or even debugger-specific feature?)

Comment: @nh_ - It's not *in the source* that this illegal line appears.  It's in the *debugger watch window*.

Comment: I've added the information that I'm working with Visual Studio. I had no idea this was relevant while I wrote the question.

Comment: As @CoryKramer said, `this` is a pointer. `this->att` is equivalent to `(*this).att`. I wonder if the debugger has referenced `this->att`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow operator `->` operates on a [pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/book/pointers) on the left, meaning that it accesses the operator pointed to by the pointer on the left. As pointed out many other places the `->` operator is a shorthand for manually dereferencing the pointer, and using the dot notation. `a->b == (*a).b`. This means that the context information it needs to look up, it can find through the pointer value. The dot operator `.` assumes that you have a reference to the object on the left, so it does not need to dereference the pointer on its left first.

If your debugger somehow allows you to get away with using the dot operator instead of the arrow operator, probably because it does not (or cannot) validate the type used, it will assume that the address of the pointer variable, and not the address held by the address pointed by the value, is the object.

In other words, it will look at an object at a location, in memory, that is not the object itself. The behaviour is most likely undefined, and you will only see garbage data, of what is actually stored at the memory offset of the member `att`.

Assume your object is layed out so that, an attribute `foo` is at offset 0, and an attribute `att` is at offset 4, then the debugger is basically looking at the address of the object instance plus whatever offset your member variable holds. I am not at my home computer, but I can add a sketch of what happens to clarify a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

`att`, by itself, returns the member variable `att` for that instance of the class.

`this->att` returns the same thing as `att` except that the `this->` explicitly tells the program to return the `att` member variable of the class.

An example of a situation when `att` and `this->att` would return different values is if `att` was redefined in a local scope inside a class. In that case, `att` would refer to the locally defined `att` and `this->att` would refer to the `att` member variable of the class.

Since `this` is a pointer to the current object, it requires the `->` notation (which is a combination of dereferencing the pointer and member/method access). The `.` notation is only member/method access. To answer your question of "what is the meaning of `this.att`", I would say it is meaningless and honestly I'm surprised it even returned anything at all.

The only "right" way you can use `this` with `.` is if you dereference the pointer first, like this:

`(*this).att`

However, the result is the same and the syntax is identical if you just use `->`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just blindly guessing without further information, but let me try to make some sense of what you see in your debugger, since this is your question right? So I will not explain the difference between `.` and `->`. Assume the following situation:

```
class CClass 
{ 
    int x; // at offset 0 of CClass
    int att; // at offset 4 of CClass
};

CClass* p = // ... (say p points to the address 0xF0 for now)

int CClass::do_something
{
    CClass q;
    CClass* r;
}
```

So, now inspecting the value of the expression `p->att` in your debugger, what the debugger does is take the value of `p` (here `0xF0`) and add the offset of `att` to it, resulting in the memory address `0xF4`. At this address read 4 bytes of memory (since we have an `int`) and interpret it as a signed integer. For the above situation, this should show the correct value of the `att` member of the object pointed to by `p`.

Now, assume you are inside the `do_something` function, where you have a stack allocated instance of `CClass`. If you now try to get the value of `q.att`, the debugger takes the address of the object itself (basically `&q`) and again adds the corresponding offset 4. Since `q` is allocated on the stack, the memory fragment at `&q + 4` is the location inside the stack frame where the value of member `att` of object `q` is stored. Everything fine so far.

Next, consider the expression `r.att`, which is not correctly typed C++, but the debugger seems to just proceed in the usual manner. It takes the address of `r` (`&r`), not the address pointed to by `r`, and again adds the offset of `att` (`4`) to it, before reading an `int` from this location. Since the address of `r` is on the stack, the resulting location `&r + 4` is not the location where the member of the object pointed to by `r` is located, but is an unrelated location inside your stack frame (like inside other local variables or a function argument).

In your situation, the same happens with `this`. Since the `this` pointer is an invisible first argument of non-`static` member functions, it is as well located in the function's stack frame. The debugger now seems to take the address where the `this` pointer is located in the stack frame, adds the corresponding offset and outputs the value of the `4` bytes found there. What the actual value is, depends on the layout of your stack frame (could be something like the return address), but it is clearly not inside the object pointed to by `this`.